# How i can place each number on an index in array,

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have 23681  its not string but integer ,  i want to make an array by placing each number on an index in php or javascript any guide would be appreciated

```
[0]=>2
[1]=>3
[2]=>6
[3]=>8
[4]=>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$array = str_split($yourNumber);
```

Your int will be casted to string automatically. So no implicit casting needed here.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript

```
result = (23681).toString().split("").map(Number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another javaScript solution without string conversion

```
var number = 12345, result=[]; 
 while(number>0) {
    result.push(number % 10); 
    number = Math.floor(a / 10); 
}
result.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

quick and easy:

```
$your_number_arr  = array_map('intval', str_split($your_number));
```

edit: integer conversion

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific. I don't know if you need this in Javascript or PHP, but here it is in php:

```
$str = ((string)$int);
$array = str_split($str);
```